# Random errors when receiving image data from my server

Tags: c#, encoder, decoder

I have a C# app.

It uploads images to my server and downloads them when necessary.

This is my client:

```
sb.Clear();
sb.Append(GeneralTags.ACTION_ADD);
sb.Append(Shared.DLE);
sb.Append("GALLERY");
sb.Append(Shared.DLE);
sb.Append(Shared.CurrentClientId);
sb.Append(Shared.DLE);
sb.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(gallery));
sb.Append(Shared.DLE);
byte[] byteArray = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes(sb.ToString());
int packetCount = 0;

using (TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient())
{
    clientSocket.Connect(GeneralTags.RASPBERRY_PI_IP_ADDRESS, GeneralTags.RASPBERRY_PI_PORT);
    using (NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream())
    {
        serverStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        List<byte> requestInBytes = new List<byte>();

        if (serverStream.CanRead)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Byte[] bytesIn = new Byte[1024];
            do
            {
                i = serverStream.Read(bytesIn, 0, bytesIn.Length);
                byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[i];
                Array.Copy(bytesIn, receivedBuffer, i);

                if (packetCount == 0)
                {
                    packetCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(receivedBuffer, 0);
                }
                requestInBytes.AddRange(receivedBuffer);
            } while (packetCount < requestInBytes.Count);

            serverStream.Close();


            var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestInBytes.ToArray(), 0, requestInBytes.ToArray().Length);
            var galleryback = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Gallery>(json);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("BACK: " + galleryback.ImageData.Length.ToString());
                ms.Write(galleryback.ImageData, 0, galleryback.ImageData.Length);
                Shared.ViewImage(Image.FromStream(ms, true));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Local Device Error");

        }
    }
}
```

This is my class object:

```
public class Gallery
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public bool IsUploaded { get; set; }
    public Int64 GalleryId { get; set; }
    public string JobRef { get; set; }
}
```

If we assume that my server is sending the entire data array back correctly (I have checked the bytes sent from server with the bytes received by my client)...

I get these type of errors:

```
Unterminated string. Expected delimiter: ". Path 'ImageData', line 1, position 5515.

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

How can I solve this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are sending a byte array with the serialized JSON as only a part of it (you append other things to the string, like `GeneralTags.ACTION_ADD` and so on), but when you receive data you try to deserialize the whole thing. Of course, since you do not have data in JSON format only, this results in `DeserializeObject` not being able to parse the data passed to it. You need to extract the serialized object in some way, for example using regex or some calculation involving substrings.

Comment: Hi thanks for your observation. I did start off with just using a Jason object and using an image object. But the image never got through ok. I was told Json does not work well with images. So I thought upload it as a byte array

Comment: Hi I am away from my PC but will look at this when back. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I don't think the problem lies in using a byte array. What I'm saying is that the string encoded from the array has more information than `DeserializeObject` should be called with.

Comment: Hi but I know my server is extracting the Json object and is sending just that back. I do know that I have to use an encoder on binary data - I will have to use a base64 encoder.  The problem is decoding and encoding the complete packet from client to server and server to client.

Comment: And I have to do it before serlizing it as a Json object.